# php mssql get some incorrect results stored procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the issue:

there is an `OrdersN` stored `procedure` with parameters: yesterday's date and company ID (0 for all companies) on `MSSQL`.

The procedure returns `500 entries, 13 fields` in every entries.
The procedure considers everything to be correct, but when I call a procedure from a php file, an incorrect value is passed in field 9, all other values are correct.

The procedure returns the following values in field 9:

3961

375

3281

34

72

189

But php file returns the following values in field 9:

1103

107

916

7

17

50
My PHP code for call stored procedure:

```
$msquery = "exec OrdersN '20180411',17005";
$msres = mssql_query($msquery,$link);
while ($f = mssql_fetch_assoc($msres)){
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>".$f['o_1']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$f['o_2']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$f['o_3']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$f['o_4']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$f['o_5']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$f['o_6']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$f['o_7']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$f['o_8']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$f['o_9']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$f['o_10']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$f['o_11']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$f['o_12']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$f['o_13']."</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
}
```

All data from `'o_1' to 'o_8'` and from `'o_10' to 'o_13'` are correct, but `'0_9'` is not correct.

I do not understand why the procedure calculates all the data correctly, and the file php displays incorrectly field `'o_9'` (only this field)

Comment: There's not enough information in this question for anyone to help. Can you show us the first few rows when you run the stored procedure through an IDE/console and also when PHP outputs it? In addition, also show us the first few lines of `var_dump($f);` within your loop.

Comment: Thank's for all. <br>
The problem is solved. forgot to put mssql_query ("SET DATEFIRST 1;", $ link), so that the beginning of the week was from Sunday, not from Monday